# POS for .NET 1.14 sticky center alignment

Tags: c#, opos, pos-for-.net

I currently have a VS2013 C# project that is referencing version 1.14 of POS for .NET to communicate with an Epson TM-H2000 OPOS printer.

I am able to print the content just fine. However, once I send the ESC sequence for center alignment (ESC|cA) on a specific line, every subsequent line continues to use center alignment. Sending the "Normal" sequence (ESC|N) doesn't change anything, not to mention that nothing is resetting at the end of each line via PrintNormal. I'm unable to determine if this is an issue with POS For .NET or the hardware itself.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to restore default left alignment after printing the center-justified line?

Comment: do you create the document for print dinamic? verify that http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/2-properties/pos.htm

Comment: I am not creating a PDF document.

Comment: your document is dinamic that main you create from your code or a suite framework?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a driver bug, so please contact EPSON.
Since it is two years passed, there is a possibility that the latest version has been fixed.

As an alternative, try left-justified escape sequence (ESC|lA).